# Determine the position of an equilibrium process

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> For the exothermic reaction of nitrogen gas with iodine solid to produce nitrogen triodide gas. Write the balanced equation including heat and select the overall direction of shift in the reaction.

I have balanced the equation: $\ce{N2 (g) + 3 I2 (g) <=> 2 NI3}$
Is this equation correct?

I am confused on how to find the overall direction of shift. Should I use the Le Chatelier's principle? If so, then I think the overall shift is a "shift to the left"/reverse reaction. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can use Le Chatelier's principle to predict the shift of the equilibrium when temperature or pressure is in- or decreased. It is stated that the reaction is exothermic, and this tells you on which side of the reaction equation the heat goes. And as both products and educts include gases, it would also be easy to predict how the equilibrium shifts when pressure is varied. I presume that the question, in its current form, is asking for the shifts that happen in all possible combinations of in- or decreased pressure or temperature.